# Wordpress pre_get_posts not changing the query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use pre_get_posts to modify the query so that only schools that give student discounts are displayed on the archive page. The field in question is called 'student_discount' and is a checkbox, it returns 1 if true.

when i use get_post_custom to echo the value it is '_student_discount: Array'.

This is what I have currently:

```
function show_discounts( $query ) {
   if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()  && is_post_type_archive( 'job_listing' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(        
        array(
              'key' => 'student_discount',
              'value' => 1,
              'compare' => '='
        ),
  ));       
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_discounts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

Change this:

```
is_post_type_archive( 'job_listing' )
```

For this:

```
$query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'job_listing' )
```

---

Result:

```
function show_discounts( $query ) {
   if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] === 'job_listing' ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(        
        array(
              'key' => 'student_discount',
              'value' => 1,
              'compare' => '='
        ),
  ));       
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_discounts' );
```

Let me know if you were able to make it work.